# Extending an existing Angular web projects with the capability to build mobile apps with NativeScript

Tags: angular, nativescript

Ive been working on a angular projet. And decided to do the mobile app of it. After looking for ways of doing it, I decided to go with NS.
So the first step, if I got it right, was to extend my existing project with the capability to build mobile apps with NativeScript, by calling: `ng add @nativescript/schematics`.
Well this does not work, ive the following error

```
    Project settings:
    {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "mainName": "main",
      "mainPath": "src/main.ts",
      "prefix": "app",
      "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "entryModuleClassName": "AppModule",
      "entryModuleImportPath": "./app/app.module",
      "entryModuleName": "App",
      "entryModulePath": "/src/app/app.module.ts",
      "entryComponentClassName": "AppComponent",
      "entryComponentImportPath": "./app.component",
      "entryComponentName": "App",
      "entryComponentPath": "/src/app/app.component.ts",
      "indexAppRootTag": "app-root"
    }
    Adding @nativescript/schematics to angular.json
    Adding {N} files
    Adding App_Resources
    Adding NativeScript specific exclusions to .gitignore
    Adding NativeScript run scripts to package.json
    Adding NativeScript Project ID to package.json
    Excluding NativeScript files from web tsconfig
    Adding Sample Shared Component
Cannot read property 'entries' of undefined
```

This only happens with my existing project. If I create a new angular app and add the ns schematics it works. I looked on the net but nothing. So any help or guidance will be very appreciated

Comment: Which version of Angular your current project is using & Whats your Angular & CLI version?

Comment: @Manoj, Current Project Angular Version: 7.0.1, Global Angular CLI Version: 7.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Instead nativescript, you can use simply Cordova. It's more easy, and maybe more lightweight.
And implement Cordova in a existing Angular project is quite easy.

You can see [this](https://medium.com/@EliaPalme/how-to-wrap-an-angular-app-with-apache-cordova-909024a25d79) post.

Comment: Hi German, thanks for your answer. But I really need to use NS in this project. I'll try to make it work with NS but if this does not work out I'll check out your link. Thanks